# How to get count of CoreData attributes with values in them

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

I have attributes that look like this:  *aStaffPosx*, where 'x' runs from 1 to 12.

What does the predicate look like so I can get a count of all of the *aStaffPosx* attributes with values in them?  This is what I have, but not sure it's right:

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aStaffPos*"];  //  read the single record
```

Comment: You have 12 different attributes with similar names? Then you need to list all 12 in your predicate.

Comment: RATS!  thanks anyway, Tom... :-{